# Creating my own permission level in GitLab

Tags: gitlab

I am evaluating GitLab for my enterprise, I really hope my assumption is wrong here because I REALLY like the product.

For my enterprise, the built in permissions are far to open.  We could lose about 2 or 3 industry certifications due to failed security audits if we turned it on with those permission levels and permissions per level.

How do I create my own security levels?  Guest and Reporter need purged from the system completely.  Enterprise Security would crucify me in the front lobby if I put those in.  Then Developer needs slashed way back in permissions, master needs slashed way back, and I need to create maybe 3 more specialists.

I know there isn't a UI to do this, but please tell me there's a file somewhere I can edit to do this.  I hate to be forced to spend 5X as much for GitHub for this single issue.

Answer (score 0):

A custom system is in discussion for quite some time now. [See the discussion here.](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/12736) Right now the only way you can modify rights is by editing the file [`ability.rb`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/app/models/ability.rb) which contains what permission a group has.

`def project_owner_rules` for instance defines what permissions the project owner has.

Keep in mind that this file **will** be overwritten with every update if you make changes, so keep a copy of your modifications around.

Comment: can you create new groups in that file?

Comment: @scphantm Creating groups is a bit more involved. Modifying group permissions is already a crazy hackaround. Files are (and I might miss some) [`member.rb`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/app/models/member.rb) [`group.rb`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/app/models/group.rb) [`user.rb`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/app/models/user.rb). I highly discourage this because it can really break things. If you want to dig around more most of the magic happens in the [model](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/tree/master/app/models).

Comment: @scphantm You could use the scrapped Guest and Reporter groups and put your specialists there. That is probably the easiest thing.